# Find the maximum value of each element in a 3D array and save them as a new array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that is roughly (x,y,z) = (100, 150, 25) and I want to find the maximum value of each x,y array element (ie, compare the [1][1] from all subarrays and find the maximum). I then want to save these values to a separate 2d array of shape (x, y) = (100, 150). I have included the below code as an example. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[6, 7], [3, 4], [2, 7]], [[1, 2], [5, 8], [3, 5]]])
print(a)

#some function that finds the maximum of each element and saves it to a new 2d array
desired_output = np.array([[6,7], [5, 8], [3, 7]])
print(desired_output)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your problem (probably):

```
a.max(axis=0)
```

Since I'm unsure of how exactly your array is formatted, you might be looking for axis=1 or axis=2. But according to the example you provided, axis=0 should be correct.

Some notes:
So, the technical shape of your array is probably (25, 100, 150). Using a different example (where all the dimensions have different numbers so we don't get confused):

```
arr = [[[x, x, x],
        [x, x, x],
        [x, x, x],
        [x, x, x]],

       [[x, x, x],
        [x, x, x],
        [x, x, x],
        [x, x, x]]]
```

arr is a 3d matrix, with dimensions 2x4x3

Why this works:
Numpy's operations, when you specify an axis, *collapse* that axis and create a new shape. Below are some examples.

Collapsing along axis 0, we get a 1x4x3 --> 4x3 shape:

```
[[x, x, x],
 [x, x, x],
 [x, x, x],
 [x, x, x]]
```

Collapsing along axis 1, we get a 2x1x3 --> 2x3 shape:

```
[[x, x, x],
 [x, x, x]]
```

Collapsing along axis 2, we get a 2x4x1 --> 2x4 shape:

```
[[x, x, x, x],
 [x, x, x, x]]
```

Comment: Exactly this. You can also do axis=(0,2) or the like to collapse among multiple axes. (And this will work for almost any numpy function you can think of, not just np.max.)

Comment: Yup. I had a typo that I just fixed btw. You call the array.max(), not np.max()